# Lost hash in url on Ipad

Tags: ipad, gmail, newsletter, hashtag

I encountered such a problem, I use a mailing service, which comes in the letter have an URL leading to a page of my site with the hash tag. On the desktop version, all goes well and the hash is not lost, but if you go to the post office with IPAD or iphone and go to the reference in the letter, it redirects you to a page and hash lost. Who is faced with a similar problem?

Comment: Please improve grammar.

Comment: I've bumped into your question once more. Grammar hasn't improved, so as much as I'd like to, I have no way to help.